# Struggling to writing in English

Tags: technical-writing, academic-writing, business-writing

I always struggle to write my ideas in English. Structuring my work/idea when it comes to writing leaves me blank.

Even when I'm very clear about what I want to write, I will still struggle with putting it on a paper. I'm more comfortable when it comes to speak in English and people have mentioned that I have a good command over the language.

I consider at intermediate level.

Is there any online/offline course, book or anything else available? Any technique to follow?

Your help on this will be much appreciated. I want to learn asap as this is affecting my professional life.

Thanks BB

Comment: How's your writing skill in your native language?

Comment: I wanted to edit your posting, but then, I decided it should be left alone for people to accurately judge your English language.

Comment: Thanks guys for the positive responses. Very useful. mhd196 - thanks for giving the correct term to my problem, writer's block. That what I'm suffering from. Let me know if there is any course to overcome this problem? Grammar and vocabulary can follow later I guess. Thanks

Comment: Welcome to Writers, @B.B. In addition to this site, you might also find [English Language Learners](http://ell.stackexchange.com/) to be helpful.

Answer (score -8, accepted):

You are facing a normal "writer's block". https://www.google.com/search?q=writer%27s+block

Comment: -1. This question is about acquiring skill in a foreign language, and has nothing to do with writer's block. Additionally, please don't use LMGTFY links here (or on other Stack Exchange sites); they're mocking and not appropriate to our site. (I might add that they're particularly ridiculous when used with a term that the original poster never mentioned.) What would be much better would be giving a link to one or two resources that seem to be helpful and relevant.

Answer (score 3):

Writer's block is probably part of it, but another part is just knowing how to make ideas and words flow grammatically. I noticed you had a few minor mistakes in grammar, such as that you should have said, "when it comes to speaking in English," and "I consider myself to be at an intermediate level." (Although I would've said "I think I'm at an..." because it's more casual.)

I think what will help you the most is reading as much as you can. The books don't have to be really hard, just whatever you enjoy, whether that's informational books or works of fiction.

I hope this helps. (:

Answer (score 2):

You should know that most people have trouble putting their ideas on paper – on the first try.

The key to good writing is rewriting. It usually takes more than one attempt to get your writing polished. I imagine this is even more true in a second language, though I'm not fluent enough in any second language to try my hand at writing.

It might be liberating for you to remember that your first draft is a long way away from your final draft. You might be able to get more ideas down in one sitting if you don't worry too much about making it perfect the first time around.

Comment: Insofar as resources go, there's the [ell.se] Stack Exchange site. They don't do proofreading there, but they might be able to help with any specific questions you have about English.

Answer (score 1):

Is it easier for you to write in another language?

If it is,
consider separating your writing into two steps:

1. Write first in your favored language to get the ideas written.
2. Then,
   once you've said what you want to say,
   translate it into English.

Comment: Thanks for your response. I've similar problem in my native language but not up to this scale

Answer (score 1):

If you have ideas and are good at speaking but just hate writing you can always try speech to text software, or record yourself with your phone and then get a transcript or just play it back and manually type it in.